# Comic with a symbiotic spaceman who meets a robot inhabited by Hitler's brain

Tags: story-identification, comics, nazis

A comic book probably of European origin from the late 1970s or early 1980s. The symbiote is a man with a small limpet-shaped node onto his cerebral cortex. This node is sentient and communicates with the man telepathically.

There were several adventures in the comic, but I only remember the last one. The symbiote traveled alone in a sail spaceship and found in the middle of space an old missile-looking derelict. This derelict contains a bulky robot somewhat similar to Maximilian from the film "The Black Hole".

[image: Maximilian in the center of the image]

It is later revealed that the robot is but a cyborg containing Hitler's brain.